# Transfer Not Sent to wallet

Tags: transactions, unconfirmed-transactions

I request payment to this address: **1MJW5uSqvsdey6DnAsMo21WZ6bhehaVtKq** but still not yet to the wallet.

https://blockchain.info/address/1MJW5uSqvsdey6DnAsMo21WZ6bhehaVtKq

Why this happen how to get back or cancell

Regards

Comment: related: [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/9046/5406)

Answer (score 2):

You provided the receiving address but not the sending address or the txid.

Is this your transaction sending 0.05277 BTC to that address?

https://blockchain.info/tx/1bd7d272d7c63984608089a31e66b05c873fd7b9d50021129b87584202438a55

If that is not your transaction then has not yet been transmitted to the network. The above transaction is the only transaction involving the address you specified: 1MJW5uSqvsdey6DnAsMo21WZ6bhehaVtKq

Where did you send the payment from? Some online exchanges say they "sent" the transaction and deduct btc from your balance before they actually transmit it. Until you see a transaction ID on the blockchain I would continue to assume it has not been sent.

How you can receive your "bitcoin back or cancel" is dependent on who controls the wallet the transaction is intended to be sent from.